# Bash script with loop does not echo

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, echo

In this script, the second echo statement doesn't do anything.

```
     #!/bin/bash

echo "Start folder create..."
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do
 foldername="${filename%.*}";
 mkdir -p "$foldername";

 mv "$filename" "$foldername";
echo "made directory $foldername" ;
done;
```

All the other commands work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it finds any zip files? Try running it with the `-x` option enabled. E.g. `bash -x thatscript`, or temporarily change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it over multi lines, but have the `;`.

Your script should look like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Start folder create..."
find . -name "*.zip" | while read filename; do

  foldername="${filename%.*}"
  mkdir -p "$foldername"    
  mv "$filename" "$foldername"
  echo "made directory $foldername"
done
```

Comment: Tim, the script as it is should work fine..the problem might be that OP does not have any `.zip` file in that directory..

Comment: @heemayl it should still echo "made directory" though :/ You're right, `;` does work.

Comment: So what is the significance of the ;

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle not sure, it's used for multiline commands to make them 1 line.

Comment: @heemayl well it seems i managed to solve the issue :P

Comment: Tim: Very vey interesting :) @JohnnyBizzle Does removing just the `;`s solve the problem ?